# -webkit-border-image with css sprites

Tags: css, css-sprites

I'm using `-webkit-border-image` to specify my main sprite image in a style.  The sprite image is a bunch of button images.  What style attributes do I use to index into my main sprite image?

```
.red {
    -webkit-border-image: url(sprite.png) 0 14 0 14;
}
```

The red button sprite is at x=0, y=21.

What attributes do I use? If it were a background I'd use `background-position`. I’m not sure what to use for `-webkit-border-image`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with `border-image`. According to [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#url), CSS3 will define new syntax for image slices and image sprites.

Answer (score 2):

I also was under the impression that sprites were not possible using border image. But I was proven wrong.

The border image syntax is as follows:

```
border-image: url([file]) [offsettop] [offsetright] [offsetbottom] [offsetleft];
```

border-image is tied to the border-width. It's possible to use the offset to choose the amount of the image to show from the origin (i.e. topoffset of 10px + border-top-width of 10px will show 10px from pixel 0 to pixel 10).

But if you use a **border-width of 0px instead, it's possible** to use the offset to hide a portion of the image. In this case you can use padding to achieve the same alignment as with border-width.

See this post (where I was corrected by Scott Murray, thanks Scott) for more info and demo:

http://alignedleft.com/blog/2010/07/using-css3-border-image-sprites-for-flexible-button-states/comment-page-1/#comment-832